# window.stop() to stop currently loading images, but load new images

Tags: javascript

I have a script that, based on certain events (user interaction, setTimeout), loads a JSON and, with the result of the JSON, loads a bunch of images. I also pre-load some images, based on the user interaction with the page. Sometimes, after the page is open for a while, the images that are loaded from the JSON start to "slow down", taking more time to load (they load ok if i refresh the page). So I started looking for a way to abort the currently loading images, and came across "window.stop()". I read the description in MDN amd in the spec, and can't understand if this is what I'm looking for.

[MDN has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop):

> The stop() method is exactly equivalent to clicking the stop button in
> the browser. Because of the order in which scripts are loaded, the
> stop() method cannot stop the document in which it is contained from
> loading, but it will stop the loading of large images, new windows,
> and other objects whose loading is deferred.

[The spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-window-stop):

> The stop() method on Window objects should, if there is an existing
> attempt to navigate the browsing context and that attempt is not
> currently running the unload a document algorithm, cancel that
> navigation; then, it must abort the active document of the browsing
> context of the Window object on which it was invoked.

and [abort a document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#abort-a-document) has

> ...Cancel any instances of the fetch algorithm in the context of this
> Document, discarding any tasks queued for them, and discarding any
> further data received from the network for them...

Does this mean that after using window.stop() I can't load any more images? I did some tests, and on Firefox, Chrome and Safari, this seems to work (image loads after window.stop), but that seems to contradict the spec.

```js
window.stop();
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = "<img src='http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/5a/2e/e9/5a2ee9b3-8f0e-4f8b-4043-dd3e3ea29766/icon128-2x.png'/>";
```

```html
<div id="c"></div>
```

Am I misreading the spec and it's safe to use this sort of code, or should I try to do it in a different way?

Comment: How many images are we talking about and what sort of file sizes?

Comment: Around 80 images at once (JSON), plus the pre-loads in groups of up to 10 (on user interaction, also related to the JSON info). 5~8Kb each. Using 10 subdomains (same server, same folder, generating the subdomain "name" from the image location, so it caches) to speed it up. Not having a problem the first time it loads after a refresh (or even the first few times), but ocassionally it stalls for a while, before loading the images

Answer (score 0):

It's synchronous call.  In you code, `window.stop()` runs, and after - the new image is loaded.   That's fine with the specs as well..

```
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = "<img src='//test.com/THIS_WILL_STOP_LOADING.png'/>";
window.stop();
document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = "<img src='//test.com/THIS_WILL_LOAD.png'/>";
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do

```
return window.stop();
```

because the script that has the `window.stop();` has been already loaded, so it will go through the end.

If you have another script after that, it will be stopped, look at the example:

```html
<div id="c"></div>
<script>window.stop(); </script>
<script>document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = "<img src='http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/5a/2e/e9/5a2ee9b3-8f0e-4f8b-4043-dd3e3ea29766/icon128-2x.png'/>";</script>
```